# How much time passed between the beginning of the series and the Season 2 finale?

Tags: falling-skies

How much time passed from the beginning of the series and the Season 2 finale? I know Three months have passed between seasons 1 and 2, and they passed some time in the John F. Kennedy High School, the abandoned airfield and the hospital.

Is there a detailed timeline somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wish I had seen this question first!

I did a pretty extensive analysis of this in your [other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22372/when-did-the-alien-invasion-happen/22440#22440) when trying to back-track to get a date for the invasion.

My conclusion, based on the weather, some stated time frames, and how fast a semi-motorized army can probably move, is that we've probably seen no more than 5-6 months pass in total during the series, meaning we're still within the same year as the initial invasion.

This is based on the assumption that they didn't spend *a lot* of time in an one place. The time they spent on the airfield or hospital seemed like days at most. However, I'm much less sure how long they were in the high school, since they seemed to be "settling in", but I wouldn't estimate more than a couple of weeks at most.